# Writing Progress status

Tags: powershell

I have an NTFS Audit script and would like to add a basic progress bar. At the moment I have a function that I call like normal, with `$i = 100` to indicate my max %. I run through the folders via

`Get-ChildItem -Path $pathToFolders -Recurse -Force | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | % {$counter++}`

To get a total number of folders, then divide my `$i` by that number to get the % increment I need to increase my progress bar by each time it evaluates a folder. Problem is it only fills the progress bar up to around 40-50% by the time the script completes? Am I missing something completely obvious?

See my code (note `$j = 0` at first):

```
# Main 
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders){
    $ACLs = Get-ACL $Folder.FullName | % { $_.Access  }
    ForEach ($ACL in $ACLs){
        $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.FileSystemRights + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $outputCSV
    }
    Write-Progress -Activity "Auditing NTFS Permissions in ${$pathToFolders}..." -Status 'Progress ->' -PercentComplete $j
    $j = $j + $i
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell's `Write-Progress` takes a number from 0 to 100 to indicate progress. What you've coded here is a number from 0 to 100, but the number represents the number of folders that have been processed (which could be 5 or 50 or 2000), which is not a percentage.

Here's what you probably need to do:

```
foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
    $ACLs = Get-ACL $Folder.FullName | % { $_.Access }
    foreach ($ACL in $ACLs)
    {
        $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.FileSystemRights + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $outputCSV
    }
    Write-Progress -Activity "Auditing NTFS Permissions in ${$pathToFolders}..." -Status 'Progress ->' -PercentComplete (([int]($j / $Folders.Count)) * 100)
    $j++
}
```

This part in particular:

```
-PercentComplete ([int](($j / $Folders.Count) * 100))
```

That will calculate the percentage correctly, assuming you increment `$j` each time it loops.

Comment: Many thanks, but this doesn't appear to work - $j is nothing, before it was merely an increasing percentage value?

Comment: You have to initialze `$j` to 0 before you start, and you don't need to use `$i` at all anymore (or you could interchange `$i` with `$j` if you want, but you only need one counter variable, not two).

Comment: Aye, I had already set $j to 0 and same result. In fact the bar just sits at 0% all the way through.

Comment: My mistake, I think I had the `[int]` cast in the wrong spot. I've edited that line above, paste it in and try again.

Comment: It just jumps from 0 to 100% in one, and then even at 100% the script hasn't completed.